# Where to put AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am following the tutorial here:  http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/ and when I ran my coding a got an error for a ANR so I was told to create an AsyncTask on the OnClick method of my RegisterActivity.java and LoginActivity.java (I am creating a userdatabase)
Here is the RegisterActivity.java and LoginActivity.java as defined by the androidhive tutorial:

RegisterActivity.java

```
package com.example.dashboardactivity;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import libary.DatabaseHandler;
import libary.UserFunctions;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
public final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
Button btnRegister;
Button btnLinkToLogin;
EditText inputFullName;
EditText inputEmail;
EditText inputPassword;
TextView registerErrorMsg;

// JSON Response node names
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
    inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerName);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerEmail);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);
    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);
    registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);

    // Register Button Click event
    Log.i(TAG, "RegisterActivity Register button Click Event" );
    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String name = inputFullName.getText().toString();
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(name, email, password);

            // check for login response
            Log.i(TAG, "RegisterActivity check for login response" );
            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        // user successfully registred
                        // Store user details in SQLite Database
                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        // Clear all previous data in database
                        userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                        
                        // Launch Dashboard Screen
                        Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);
                        // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                        dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(dashboard);
                        // Close Registration Screen
                        finish();
                    }else{
                        // Error in registration
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occured in registration");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    // Link to Login Screen
    Log.i(TAG, "RegisterActivity Link to Login Screen" );
    btnLinkToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            // Close Registration View
            finish();
        }
    });
}
}
```

LoginActivity.java

```
package com.example.dashboardactivity;

import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import libary.DatabaseHandler;
import libary.UserFunctions;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
public final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
Button btnLogin;
Button btnLinkToRegister;
EditText inputEmail;
EditText inputPassword;
TextView loginErrorMsg;

// JSON Response node names
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
    loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);

    // Login button Click Event
    Log.i(TAG, "LoginActivity Login button Click Event" );
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);
 Log.i(TAG, "checking for login response");
            // check for login response
            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        // user successfully logged in
                        // Store user details in SQLite Database
                        libary.DatabaseHandler db = new libary.DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        // Clear all previous data in database
                        userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                        

                        // Launch Dashboard Screen
                        Log.i(TAG, "LoginActivity Launch Dashboard Screen" );
                        Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);

                        // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                        dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(dashboard);

                        // Close Login Screen
                        finish();
                    }else{
                        // Error in login
                        loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    // Link to Register Screen
    Log.i(TAG, "LoginActivity btnLinkToRegister" );
    btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Now I am worried that if I completely change the OnClick methods, my app won't run the same. I was told to use the coding:

```
// Login button Click Event
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
    new AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject>(){
        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) { //This is run on a background thread
            String email = args[0];
            String password = args[1];
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);
            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) { //This is run on the UI thread
            if(json != null){
                //... update the user interface ...
            }else{
                Log.e("LoginTask", "No login response was received");
            }
            super.onPostExecute(json);
        }

    }.execute(inputEmail.getText().toString(), inputPassword.getText().toString());
}
});
```

I have never worked with AsyncTasks before so should I just switch out the current coding with the one I was given as a template, and if so will that affect how my app works? Or should I just implement the coding as a new AsyncTask and where would I put that in my RegistrationActivity.java/LoginActivity.java? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Refer this http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/05/painless-threading.html
.It will solve your concerns :)

Comment: Thank you. But just to make sure I'm understanding right, so by changing the onClick method to what I was recommended to use, the app will still run the same? (except correctly this time with the lengthy stuff acting in the background and not bogging up my UI Thread)?

Comment: Oh ok so the thing that is bugging me is if that recommended coding is for the ENTIRE onClick method or just for a part of it. If you can help clear that up that would also be really reassuring, otherwise I can just ask the person who suggested it :)

Comment: It is always best practice to run long running operations like JSON or XML parsing, Web service calls etc... on background thread. In your case the App will still run the same and it will also be using best practices. Let me know if you need anything else.